# simple slope analsis significance testing

Tags: regression, interaction

let's say that I have this model below:

lm(academic_peformance ~ biological_sex(binary) + age + history_score + math_score+
history_score:math_score)

I want to test simple slope analysis to probe interaction (math:history)
but due to the biological sex being binary,

I was wondering what should I do to run the significance test for a simple slope analysis.

(like, I want to test the simple slope analysis with + 1 sd, -sd for math score to probe math:history interaction)

How can I conduct simple slope ?

I will plug mean of age to age, but really don't know what should I do to deal with categorical covariate.

Comment: Your question is awfully cryptic. Include more details about what you are trying to learn from the data, and you are likely to get thoughtful responses. It isn't clear to me what you mean by "simplified slope analysis" or "probe. interaction"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model, neither `biological_sex(binary)` nor `age` is involved in the interaction term, so each of them just provides an additive contribution to outcome regardless of the values of `history_score` and `math_score`. Thus you can choose whichever `biological_sex(binary)` value that you want, and the analysis of the `history_score:math_score` interaction will be the same. The only difference would be in the absolute values of the predicted outcomes, not in the slopes with respect to `history_score` and `math_score`.